# Drop down List issue when making as non editable

Tags: php

I have a task assignment site. I create task for a person in activity.php

I can edit the activity in edit.pgp page.

I am retreiving the selected value for a drop down.

```
<b>Assignee: &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp </b><select name = "assignee"  id="assignee">
    <option <?php if ($assignee == $assignee) { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>><?php echo $assignee ?></option>
  <option <?php echo $bssignee ?> </option>
```

It displays the user which has been selected in previous screen.(activity.php)

I wanted to make the drop down as non editable. So i changed the code as

```
<b>Assignee: &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp </b><select name = "assignee" disabled = "disabled" id="assignee">
    <option <?php if ($assignee == $assignee) { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>><?php echo $assignee ?></option>
  <option <?php echo $bssignee ?> </option>
```

But after that whenever I submit the value in edit.php. The dropdown value is getting saved as null or blank.

Also When I dont make it as non editable. Even without changing the value it saves the value.

So how can I make the value to be saved and user not able to change the dropdown value ?

Comment: Why are you putting spaces between attribute names and values?

Answer (score 0):

Disabling a field prevents it from being included in the post message.